Error running USPEX with VASP locally
I am a beginner in USPEX, particularly trying to run EX01. However, I am running into the following errors:
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by vasp_std)
vasp_std: /home/sourav//v91/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by vasp_std)

I have tried running export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu at my USPEX calculation directory, but could not resolve the issue.
Following is my input file:
PARAMETERS EVOLUTIONARY ALGORITHM
******************************************
*      TYPE OF RUN AND SYSTEM            *
******************************************
USPEX : calculationMethod (USPEX, VCNEB, META)
300   : calculationType (dimension: 0-3; molecule: 0/1; varcomp: 0/1)
1     : AutoFrac

% optType
1
% EndOptType

% atomType
Si
% EndAtomType

% numSpecies
4
% EndNumSpecies
******************************************
*               POPULATION               *
******************************************
20    : populationSize (how many individuals per generation)
30    : initialPopSize 
25    : numGenerations (how many generations shall be calculated)
8     : stopCrit 
0     : reoptOld 
0.6   : bestFrac 
******************************************
*          VARIATION OPERATORS           *
******************************************
0     : fracTopRand
0.50  : fracGene (fraction of generation produced by heredity)
0.30  : fracRand (fraction of generation produced randomly from space groups)
0.20  : fracAtomsMut (fraction of the generation produced by softmutation)
0.00  : fracLatMut (fraction of the generation produced by softmutation)
0.00  : fracPerm
*****************************************
*   DETAILS OF AB INITIO CALCULATIONS   * 
*****************************************
% abinitioCode
1 1 1 1 1 1
% ENDabinit

% KresolStart
0.13 0.11 0.09 0.07 0.05 0.04
% Kresolend

% commandExecutable
srun /tools/vasp.6.4.1/bin/vasp_std
% EndExecutable

0       : whichCluster (0: no-job-script, 1: local submission, 2: remote submission)
1     : numParallelCalcs


I got the issue fixed
Reference:https://groups.google.com/g/uspex/c/h0NiBPT_ivw/m/AyssF3bQAgAJ
This issue may be related to a version conflict between system libraries and the libstdc++ version included with MATLAB. You may be able to resolve this issue by making MATLAB use your system's libstdc++ instead of the libstdc++ shipped with MATLAB. While you can accomplish this in the way described by Joseph above, there is a better way:
From a Linux shell (with appropriate permissions to make modifications in your MATLAB installation, i.e. use "sudo" if needed or work with your system administrator):

cd into your MATLAB sys/os/glnxa64 directory.
Create a new directory named "old":
mkdir old
Move libstdc++* into the old directory:
copy system libstdc++ file from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 and paste it in glnxa64 folder

